# App Crashes in Samsung Galaxy Note 4 LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, galaxy

I have an app on the play store. It works fine for all devices except for the Samsung Galaxy S4. The app is built using LibGDX. The users complains  that it crashes on startup. Can anyone tell me what direction to look to fix the problem? Here is the code:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements         IActivityRequestHandler {

      AdView adView;
      int other=-1;
      private final int BIG_ADS = 2;  
     private final int SHOW_ADS = 1;
     private final int HIDE_ADS = 0;

        protected Handler handler = new Handler()
        {


            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch(msg.what) {
                    case SHOW_ADS:
                    {
                        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    }
                    case HIDE_ADS:
                    {
                        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                         show();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        public void show()
        {
              other++;
              if(other==1)
              {
              AdBuddiz.showAd(this);
              other=-1;
              }
        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          AdBuddiz.setPublisherKey("Secret");
          AdBuddiz.cacheAds(this);


         // Create the layout
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

        // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

        // Create the libgdx View
        View gameView = initializeForView(new AntiBully(this), config);

        // Create and setup the AdMob view
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdUnitId("Secret");
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
        .build());

        // Add the libgdx view
        layout.addView(gameView);

        // Add the AdMob view
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

        layout.addView(adView, adParams);

        // Hook it all up
        setContentView(layout);
    }

     // This is the callback that posts a message for the handler
    public void showAds(int show) {
       handler.sendEmptyMessage(show);
    }

    public AndroidApplication returnThis()
    {
     return this;
    }




}
```

Here is the Stack Trace:

```
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/trltespr/trltespr:5.0.1/LRX22C/N910PVPU3BOF5:user/release-keys'
Revision: '12'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 17354, tid: 17374, name: GLThread 2400 >>> com.mygdx.highjumper.android <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
r0 00000000 r1 000043de r2 00000006 r3 00000000
r4 af6f2db8 r5 00000006 r6 00000016 r7 0000010c
r8 a22b0140 r9 00000000 sl 00000001 fp a2265de0
ip 000043de sp af6f2820 lr b6f42fe1 pc b6f66980 cpsr 60070010

backtrace:
#00 pc 00037980 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 pc 00013fdd /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
#02 pc 00014bfb /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03 pc 00011541 /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
#04 pc 0000fccc /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05 pc 00001259 /system/lib/libstdc++.so
#06 pc 00000afb /system/lib/libstdc++.so (__cxa_pure_virtual+6)
#07 pc 000e4595 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxGlObject::DecRefCount(EsxContext*)+28)
#08 pc 000b4b67 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::GlUseProgram(unsigned int)+150)
#09 pc 000e02d3 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxGlApiParamValidate::GlUseProgram(EsxDispatch*, unsigned int)+34)
#10 pc 000abd75 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (glUseProgram+44)
#11 pc 0031ff8f /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.mygdx.highjumper.android-1@base.apk@classes.dex
```

Thanks,

Isaiah Thompson